# Freeing space on Ubuntu does not work

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space-utilization

The df command tells me I have no free space left on the root drive

http://cl.ly/image/212N1F2T0t19

but I deleted a lot of files on the root and still this does not freeing up space.
This is the result without the home folder, because home is not mounted on root

http://cl.ly/image/3J1O3e2l0G09

the 19GB from the df command is not the same as the 9,8GB  from the du command?

I deleted all the data with "rm" commands so I guess the data is really gone and not caching up somewhere...

Does any body know what's going on here, and how I can free some space?

Answer (score 1):

Are the files still open?
That would explain the space not being reclaimed.

You may want to use `lsof` to check which process has your unlinked files open.